# Why was erlang:now() specced such that it may skew the time of a node?

Tags: erlang, language-design

the erlang documentation says:

***erlang:now()***
*[...] It is also guaranteed that subsequent calls to this BIF returns continuously increasing values. Hence, the return value from now() can be used to generate unique time-stamps, and if it is called in a tight loop on a fast machine the time of the node can become skewed. [...]*

I find this a little strange (especially considering that the granularity is microsecond). Why was it specced this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it can then be used to uniquely generate timestamp numbers. The `os` module has a variant which does not do that.

Comment: So when it says "the time of the node can become skewed" it really means, "the time of now() can become skewed"?

Comment: Yes, based on this source code it is apparent that the system clock is not modified when the skew happens, only the internal state of the Erlang VM gets skewed a bit when needed: http://code.google.com/p/erlang/source/browse/trunk/erts/emulator/beam/erl_time_sup.c?r=88#662 (This skew will be temporary until the system clock catches up, i.e. if you skew in a tight loop, then sleep, results will go back to normal when checking later.)